# Possible reasons with OGONE post payment response failure on redirection url's

Tags: ios, web, e-commerce, payment, checkout

We are using **OGONE** e-commerce solution for the payment checkouts.

**In a valid scenario, we have ACCEPT-URL,DECLINE-URL & EXCEPTION-URL to get post payment response from OGONE payment gateway.**

**Problem:** we are getting few failure cases after successful payment on OGONE Gateway, but our system is not being updated for post payment response.

If we look at the above mentioned problem, there are 2 possible reasons comes in mind,

1. OGONE did not responded after successful payment to our clients(Web,IOS,Android) so we did not get confirmation on our server.
2. After payment deduction on OGONE and before capturing response from redirection URLS, some issue happened with user device connection.
3. May be user quit the application in between two steps mentioned in point 2 above.

We are unable to find a valid and exact reasons for payment response failure, So and Guru who came across these kind of issue. I know this question looks theoretical but Any help or clue can save my time.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason to my problem. The method we were using to capture the response over redirection urls since day first was

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {}
```

but now it start missing the response over redirection URL. During analysis we found response was captured in

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {}
```

but was missed in first method call back. **Happy coding.**